Data modelling for inhomogeneous clutter scenarios
In my previous post What features can be used to estimate both azimuth and elevation angle using a deep learning model?, I uploaded a signal model that is used for DOA estimation, but I haven't considered the case regarding inhomogeneous clutter scenarios, e.g. influence of land-water transitions, large masts, wind turbines, buildings, etc. How will the model change when these scenarios are considered? Any suggestion will be helpful.

What have your efforts to answer this question yielded? Is there something in particular that you do not understand and would like help on?

@AnonSubmitter85, I didn't come across any paper or any resources that will help me understand. If you know any, maybe you can suggest

A simple google search yields oh so many results.

It's great that you have developed an interest in radar and there are many people here who will gladly help. However, your questions are very low-effort and show that you are not doing research much on your own or putting in much effort. Perhaps I am in the minority here, but we are not chatbots to be tasked with rudimentary information gathering assignments.

@AnonSubmitter85, yes a simple google search doesn't give clear explanations on how it affects the array manifolds.

The search provides the starting point for your own research. Good luck.
